# Setting compiler options for intero in emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs, intero

When I am developing I like to have `-fdefer-type-errors` and `-XPartialTypeSignatures` enabled. Currently I just add

```
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fdefer-type-errors #-}
```

to the top of the file I am working with. However this is not ideal as I often forget to remove these lines once I am done. Is there an option to pass these to intero in emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can now be archived by setting `intero-extra-ghc-options` and `intero-extra-ghci-options`.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your cabal file to specify the relevant extensions and ghc-options should work, i.e.:

```
...
lib
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  ghc-options:         -fdefer-type-errors
  extensions:          PartialTypeSignatures
```

Comment: This is not an option, I want those options only in intero when I am developing. When I normally compile the project I do not want these to be enabled. Also I do not want to have them appear in any files that are actually tracked in the repo.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I don't know of a way to accomplish that.